# convert an array of int in json, in java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I want to know how can I do to convert an array of int in json.
My array was created in java and then I want a jsonarray/Object ?
This is my code :

```
int tableau[]=new int[6];
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();  


int k=0;
for(k=0; k<6; k++){
    tableau[k]=k;
    System.out.print(tableau[k]);
    list.add((Object)tableau[k]);

}
```

Comment: How are you not able to google that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research or effort.

Answer (score 1):

`JSONArray` doesn't have `add` method, so you can't use

```
list.add((Object)tableau[k]);
```

But you can use `put(int)` instead.

```
list.put(tableau[k]);
```

You can also first fill your array with data and use `JSONArray(Object array)` which will test if object you try to put is in fact array, and then (with little help if reflection and its `Array.get(array, i)` method) will iterate over array and use `put` for you. So your code can also look like

```
for(..){
   //fill tableau array with data
}
JSONArray list = new JSONArray(tableau);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a JSONArray from array object. So your example can be done like

```
    int tableau[] = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    JSONArray list = new JSONArray(tableau);
```

Comment: I also thought about this but form example in question it looks like OP may be getting values dynamically inside loop. But yes, after values ware put in array `new JSONArray(tableau)` could be simpler than `put`. +1.